# Where is the implementation of all the methods (roundCentury, addDay, addDays...) in nesbot/carbon library in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-8, php-carbon

I try to look at all the files in nesbot/carbon vendor source code but still can't find the implementation of some methods likes roundCentury, addDay, addDays... except the php docblock.

Because I want to know how these methods work.
I wonder where is implementation of these method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried their GitHub?

Comment: Have you searched for `roundCentury` in your code?

Comment: @brombeer The question says that yes, they have. And if you do, you'll see that they are right: these methods are implemented using some kind of "macro" system, not on the objects themselves.

Comment: @LajosArpad It's not their code, it's a third-party library; and the question already says that they've looked.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm aware of that. But it may be inside the vendor folder. I would always start searching for it locally, because if I find the exact code that is being run, then I exclude misunderstandings from version differences. If it is not found, then I would look online.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code structure of Carbon is rather complicated, including heavy use of [PHP traits](https://www.php.net/trait) and [a custom "macro" system](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-macro), but eventually I tracked down the definition to `Carbon\Traits\Date` which is included into the main classes like `Carbon\Carbon`.

This doesn't define the methods *directly*, but rather implements [method overloading via `__call`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods), where the method name is passed in as a string. The Carbon code actually *parses the method name* to decide what it should do.

For rounding, that calls `roundMethod`, which is defined in *another trait*, called `Carbon\Traits\IntervalRounding`, the main line of which is this:

```
return $this->{$action.'Unit'}(substr($method, \strlen($action)), ...$parameters);
```

For `roundCentury`, `$action` is "round", and the `substr` part takes the rest of the name, so you get:

```
return $this->roundUnit('Century', ...$parameters);
```

The definition of `roundUnit` is then in *yet another* trait, `Carbon\Traits\Rounding`.

The "add..." methods presumably work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

`round***` supports dynamically any unit, so there is no hard-coded method for each of them but one single method and `__call()` takes care to parse the method name and select the appropriate unit:
https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/b017c794d31626a324c8216ff222fb895306c911/src/Carbon/Traits/Rounding.php#L40

Answer (score 1):

A function with the name addDay is not listed in the sources of Carbon. It is therefore difficult to find the place where the actual action takes place. When addDay is called, the magic function __call() in Traits/Date.php becomes active. There it is split into an "add" action and a "Day" unit and branched to addUnit() method. There we will find the actual action:

```
$date = $date->modify("$value $unit");
```